# Умножить число на строку с арифметическими операторами

Tags: javascript

Как произвести арифметические операции в строке?

```
5 * "3 * 1"
```

`parseInt` не работает

Comment: убрать кавычки и сделать eval?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

По простому `eval`

```js
const a = 5;
const b = "*3";
console.log(eval(a + b));
```

по умному - парсингом строки

```js
const a = 5;
const b = "*3";
const c = parseInt(b.substring(1));
let res;
switch (b.charAt(0)) {
  case '+': res = a + c; break;
  case '-': res = a - c; break;
  case '*': res = a * c; break;
  case '/': res = a / c; break;
}
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 6):

По-умному, используя `Function` как более безопасную альтернативу `eval`:

```js
console.log(calc(5, '*3')); 
console.log(calc('6 / 2 * Math.sqrt(25) + 17')); 

function calc() {
  return Function(`"use strict"; return (${[...arguments].join('')});`)(); 
}
```