# Правильное ли решение этой задании таким образом?

Tags: javascript, инспекция-кода

> Создайте функцию конструктор Calculator, которая создаёт «расширяемые» объекты калькулятора. Реализуйте метод calculate(str), который принимает строку типа "1 + 2" в формате «ЧИСЛО оператор ЧИСЛО» (разделено пробелами) и возвращает результат. Метод должен понимать плюс `+` и минус `-`.

Я так решила. Понимаю что многое не совпадает(возможно(возможно нет, так и есть) способ решения тоже неправильный), но результат такой который требуется в задании.

```js
function Calculator(add, sub) {
  this.add = add;
  this.sub = sub;
  this.addition = function() {
    let arrAdd = add.split(" + ");
    console.log(arrAdd)
    let array = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < arrAdd.length; i++) {
      array.push(parseInt(arrAdd[i]));
    }
    console.log(array)
    let plus = array[0] + array[1];
    console.log(plus);
  };

  this.subtraction = function() {
    let arrSub = sub.split(" - ");
    console.log(arrSub);
    let array = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < arrSub.length; i++) {
      array.push(parseInt(arrSub[i]));
    }
    console.log(array)

    let minus = array[0] - array[1];
    console.log(minus);

  }

}

let calculator = new Calculator("1 + 2", "12 - 4");
calculator.addition();
calculator.subtraction();
```

P.S. Думаю каждый раз придется добавить метод и для других операций. Наверное можно было создать один метод, и код меньше было бы тогда и скорость выполнения уменьшилось бы.

**Более соответствующее решение задании**

```js
function Calculator(str){
  this.str=str;
  this.calculate=function(){
    let array=str.split(" ");
    console.log(array);
    let a=+(array[0]);
    let b=+(array[2]);
    if(array[1]=="+"){
      let plus=a+b;
      console.log(plus);
    }

    else if(array[1]=="-"){
      let minus=a-b;
      console.log(minus);
    }
  }
}
let calc=new Calculator("4 + 7");
calc.calculate();
let calc1=new Calculator("120 - 10");
calc1.calculate();
```

**Version 3**

```js
function Calculator(str){
  
  this.str=str,
  this.calculate=function(str){
    let array=str.split(" ");
    let a=+(array[0]);
    let b=+(array[2]);

    if(array[1]==="+"){
      let plus=a+b;
      console.log("10 + 9=" + plus); 
    }

    else if(array[1]==="-"){
      let minus=a-b;
      console.log("1111 - 1=" + minus);
    }

    else if(array[1]==="*"){
      let multi=a*b;
      console.log("5 * 5=" + multi);
    }
    else if(array[1]==="/"){
      let del=a/b;
      console.log("164 / 4=" + del);
    }

    else if(array[1]==="%"){
      let modulo=a%b;
      console.log("19 % 5=" + modulo);
    }
    
  }
}

let calc= new Calculator();
calc.calculate("10 + 9");
calc.calculate("1111 - 1");
calc.calculate("5 * 5");
calc.calculate("164 / 4");
calc.calculate("19 % 5");
```

**Version 4**

```js
function Calculator(str){
  this.str=str,
  this.calculate=function(str){
    let array=str.split(" ");
    let a=+(array[0]);
    let b=+(array[2]);

    if(array[1]==="+"){
      let plus=a+b;
      return plus;
    }
  }
  
}

let calc= new Calculator();
let result=calc.calculate("10 + 9");
console.log(result);
```

Comment: А в чем вопрос?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Умножить число на строку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1049312/%d0%a3%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83)

Comment: В условии требовалась функция с одним параметром, а у Вас получился объект с конструктором из двух параметров. Как бы тут мало общего с условием.

Comment: function calculate(str) {return eval(str);}
console.log(calculate("1 + 2"));

Comment: Это немного лучше, но все равно не соответствует. Требуется чтобы возвращалось значение. То есть должно быть можно написать, например, `console.log('2+2 = ', calculate('2+2'))` и получить в консоли "2 + 2 = 4".

Comment: @Yaant & Anton Shchyrov & hu-fo-of-ex Я это предложение забыла вставить (-_-) : Создайте функцию конструктор Calculator, которая создаёт «расширяемые» объекты калькулятора. Поэтому я через конструктор создала

Comment: Ну это не отменяет того факта, что метод должен возвращать результат. И вызываться он должен не как `let calc=new Calculator("4 + 7"); calc.calculate();`, а как-нибудь навроде этого: `let calc=new Calculator(); let result = calc.calculate("4 + 7");`

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov

Comment: @hu-fo-of-ex ,,

Comment: @Yaant Окей, щас заново попробую исправить

Comment: @Yaant Вы наверное такое решение имели ввиду. Это правильно? P.S. Код выше вставила

Comment: "метод возвращает результат" - вот это вот из условия у Вас где? Вывод в консоль - это не возврат результата

Comment: @Yaant Version 4 вставлено выше. Проверьте плиз

Comment: Теперь да :) вот только `this.str = str ` тут лишнее, это поле у Вас никак не используется. :)

Comment: @Yaant Finally :) Да заметила, просто она не мешала, так и забыла осталась она там ) Спасибо вам )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Не работает с отрицательными числами

Я бы сделал вот так:

```js
function Calculator(funcs) {
  this.funcs = funcs
}

Calculator.prototype.calculate = function (str) {
  var parts = str.match(/\d+\.?\d*|\.\d+|((?!\s)\D)+/g)
  return parts && this.funcs[parts[1]] && this.funcs[parts[1]](+parts[0], +parts[2])
}

var c1 = new Calculator({
  '+': (x, y) => x + y,
  '-': (x, y) => x - y,
})

var c2 = new Calculator({
  '+': (x, y) => x + y,
  '-': (x, y) => x - y,
  '*': (x, y) => x * y,
})

for (var c of [c1, c2]) {
  console.log(c.calculate("12-2"))
  console.log(c.calculate("12 + 4"))
  console.log(c.calculate("12 * 3"))
  console.log(c.calculate("4.8 + .5"))
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh }
```

## Работает с отрицательными числами

Поскольку в условии сказано, что пробелы всегда есть, можно сделать так:

```js
function Calculator(funcs) {
  this.funcs = funcs
}

Calculator.prototype.calculate = function (str) {
  var parts = str.split(/\s+/)
  return parts && this.funcs[parts[1]] && this.funcs[parts[1]](+parts[0], +parts[2])
}

var c1 = new Calculator({
  '+': (x, y) => x + y,
  '-': (x, y) => x - y,
})

var c2 = new Calculator({
  '+': (x, y) => x + y,
  '-': (x, y) => x - y,
  '*': (x, y) => x * y,
})

function check(s) {
  console.log([s, c1.calculate(s), c2.calculate(s)].map(x => (""+x).padStart(16)).join(" "))
}

check("12 - 2")
check("12 + 4")
check("12 + -4")
check("-12 + -4")
check("-12 + 4")
check("12 * 3")
check("4.8 + .5")
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh }
```

Если хочется без пробелов, то можно так:

```js
function Calculator(funcs) {
  this.funcs = funcs
}

Calculator.prototype.calculate = function (str) {
  var [l, o, r] = str.match(/-?\d+\.?\d*|-?\.\d+|((?!\s|-\d)\D)+/g) || []
  if (!r&& o[0] === '-') r = o.slice(1), o = o[0]
  return this.funcs[o] && this.funcs[o](+l, +r)
}

var c1 = new Calculator({
  '+': (x, y) => x + y,
  '-': (x, y) => x - y,
})

var c2 = new Calculator({
  '+': (x, y) => x + y,
  '-': (x, y) => x - y,
  '*': (x, y) => x * y,
})

function check(s) {
  console.log([s, c1.calculate(s), c2.calculate(s)].map(x => (""+x).padStart(16)).join(" "))
}

check("12 - 2")
check("12 + 4")
check("12 + -4")
check("-12 + -4")
check("-12 + 4")
check("12 * 3")
check("12-2")
check("12+4")
check("12+-4")
check("-12+-4")
check("-12+4")
check("12--4")
check("-12--4")
check("-12-4")
check("4.8 + .5")
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh }
```

Comment: Интересное решение. Я правильно поняла эти регулярные выражения (/\d+\.?\d*|\.\d+|((?!\s)\D)+/g). \d=означает соответствие 1 или более раз любой цифры. \.?= соответствие 0 или более раз любого символа. \d*=соответствие 0 или более раз любой цифры.Первый символ |= именно в этом выражении это выбор либо \.?\d* либо \.\d+. А это ((?!\s)\D)+/g)= глобальное соответствие любому не цифровому символу если после выражения которое стоит до 2-го символа | не идет пробел. И при 2-ом символе | выбирается либо выражение после него или до него, смотря какое значение мы подали в метод calculate().

Comment: @devafina, нет, не любого символа. Про кусок со `\D` - вообще нет. Про `|` вообще не понял. И ещё, я тут понял, что с отрицательными числами не работает.

Comment: @devafina, поправил отрицательные числа.

Comment: Если убрать `/-?\d+  { \.?\d*|-?\.\d+ }   |((?!\s|-\d)\D)+/g`  внутри RegExp, то все правильно работает. Это там точно не лишнее? То что я отметила между фигурными скобками. В другом варианте которую вы добавили раньше там тоже без  этого `\.?\d*|-?\.\d+` все правильно работает.  P.S. У меня что-то в комменте форматирование не работает

Comment: @devafina, числа бывают дробными. Добавил в тесты `"4.8 + .5"`. А в комментах форматирование ограничено.

Comment: Я знаю что числа бывают дробными, Я просто про них в этом задании забыла, ибо во всем стараюсь разобраться иногда параллельно иногда последовательно )

Answer (score 0):

Понимаю, что это троллинг, но самая короткая реализация  метода это:

```
function calculate(str) {
  //  Проверяем регулярным выраженем str
// Если не соответствует образцу число оп число 
// возвращаем NaN
  return eval(str);
}
```

Comment: но и самая опасная

Comment: Согласен. Не это ждут от студентов. Но, на всякий случай, чтобы автор вопроса знал и о такой возможности.

Comment: @JegorsČemisovs <Что будет, если строкой, которую мы решим скормить eval'у, окажется os.system('rm -rf /')? Интерпретатор честно запустит процесс удаления всех данных с компьютера.>  Думаю будет "easy"

Comment: Да, поэтому эту функцию используют редко. Нужно предварительно проверить рег.выражением на соответствие образцу. Если тест провален — возвращаем NaN или что другое, иначе — запускаем eval будучи уверены, что там 2 + 2, а не rm -rf.

Comment: @JegorsČemisovs Да понятно, спасибо